# Is there a use case describing the need to perform xenon propellant offloading?

Tags: propulsion, ion-thruster

I can understand hydrazine offloading and the hazards associated, but I'm wondering if there is such a need for xenon offloading.

Comment: Xenon is not explosive, toxic or cancerogenic but narcotic and very expensive. Venting some of it should be avoided anyway.

Comment: I don't think it ever happened. I suspected this to be the case for [Akatsuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akatsuki_(spacecraft)), when its main engine failed and it used RCS for orbital insertion - dumping fuel for non-functional engine would be a reasonable move - but Akatsuki used a standard hypergolic bipropellant for main engine (hydrazine-dinitrogen tetroxide), not xenon.

Comment: As hypotetical case - offloading before launch, say because a technical issue found. I don't know did it ever hapeened.

Comment: Seems to me it would be irresponsible not to have a procedure to offload a high pressure gas, e.g. in that sense xenon is no different to the helium used as a pressurant gas (300bar) for bipropellant engines.

Comment: @Uwe - Yes re: rare and expensive. I've yet to find any web references that give reason for offloading

Comment: @Heopps The example of a technical issue was brought up during the very brief discussion we had. I hop tot talk to our propulsion subsystem lead when he returns from travel.

Comment: @Puffin - Agreed. I'm trying to identify a such a procedure and any associated hazards, but a bit surprised to have not fouind any references online....yet. Thanks

Comment: Inhaling xenon may be a hazard due to its narcotic effect even if there is still enough oxygen within the breathed gas mixture. Xenon may be used in small quantities for anaesthesia.

Comment: I was thinking that the pressure vessel, when fully pressurised, is a stored energy hazard in its own right. It makes sense that you'd want to limit access to that area. I've assumed that this is normal practice for bi-propellant systems.